# How do I install extra modules for postgresql 9.2? like cube.control?

Tags: postgresql

I installed postgresql 9.2 via macports. Usually I can install an extension by just running the 'create extension' command in the database I'm using. And while it works for fuzzystrmatch, I can't find the appropriate file for the cube module. The following are the modules I have installed.

```
select * from pg_available_extensions;
 name        | default_version | installed_version |                                  -
 adminpack          | 1.0             |                   | administrative functions for      PostgreSQL
 dblink             | 1.0             |                   | connect to other PostgreSQL databases from within a database
 file_fdw           | 1.0             |                   | foreign-data wrapper for flat file access
 fuzzystrmatch      | 1.0             | 1.0               | determine similarities and distance between strings
 lo                 | 1.0             |                   | Large Object maintenance
 pageinspect        | 1.0             |                   | inspect the contents of database pages at a low level
pg_buffercache     | 1.0             |                   | examine the shared buffer cache
pg_freespacemap    | 1.0             |                   | examine the free space map (FSM)
pg_stat_statements | 1.1             |                   | track execution statistics of all SQL statements executed
pg_trgm            | 1.0             | 1.0               | text similarity measurement and index searching based on trigrams
pgcrypto           | 1.0             |                   | cryptographic functions
pgrowlocks         | 1.0             |                   | show row-level locking information
pgstattuple        | 1.0             |                   | show tuple-level statistics
plpgsql            | 1.0             | 1.0               | PL/pgSQL procedural language
tablefunc          | 1.0             | 1.0               | functions that manipulate whole tables, including crosstab
uuid-ossp          | 1.0             |                   | generate universally unique identifiers (UUIDs)
(16 rows)
```

Where can I download the other missing modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install it via https://postgresapp.com you it should come with those additional extensions and PostGIS and PLV8 as well.